# javascript codes aren't executed when including page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I included some page in my angularjs-based page like this:

```
<div data-ng-include src="includehtml"></div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.selectImage = function(id) {$scope.includehtml = id;}
```

(I send html file address as a parameter when calling the function selectImage() Like the bellow code)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="selectImage('lists/1.html');"></a>
```

In the end of file 1.html, I've a javascript internal code. That code isn't executed when I include 1.html file via clicking on the link (The link that sends file url to function selectImage() )

I want to know how can I change my code to execute the javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
<div data-ng-include="includehtml"></div>
```

[`ngInclude` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Comment: That's not the problem, My method is one of the AngularJS file including methods, You can try it, it works also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use src attribute than your div should look like the below one;

```
<div data-ng-include="" src="includehtml"></div>
```

You should prevent the default action of anchor element by using the following  code.

```
<a class=”button” href=”#” id=”selectImage” ng-click=”selectImage($event, 'imgLoc')”>Select Image</a>


    $scope.selectImage = function (event, imgloc) {
    event.preventDefault();
   // do your action here
    };
```

Comment: I know that it's not the problem, However I replaced my code with yours, but nothin' changed...